# SQL database table event listener

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Long time reader, first time lister!

I have a project that I'm working on and need to know whether anyone has any ideas or tips... So I have an SQL database that I connect via an ODBC connection and only have read access. What I want to do is create some sort of listener for when a particular table is updated which will then call a PHP script. Much like an event trigger but I don't have access to the server.

Is there some mysterious PHP library that can handle this or a third party application that can be run on a server and plug into a database?

Thanks!

Comment: what you have tried please show the code

Comment: What code @Mr.Pyramid? I'm merely asking for suggestions or pointers to start!

Comment: @lrey that means the question is off topic. This stack is for specific questions with examples of what you have tried before. Suggestions and "how to get started" questions are **explicitly** not allowed. Here's the allowed and disallowed topics: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a `while(true)` loop in my PHP script until it found the record that it was looking for which was called from a jquery ajax call. A little 'hackish' but I was under a bit of time pressure!! :)